Inputs not being passed to step?
I'm trying to set up an automation ("bot") with Google Appsheet. What I want is when a new entry is made to a table, pass that entry (or at the very least, the row number) to an Apps Script function. My function just returns the value for now while I'm trying to get this working:
function myFunc(value) {
    Logger.log(value)
    return value
}

Here is what the bot configuration looks like:
The "event" is when data is added to a table.
The "step" calls my app script. This is the step settings:

Function Name: myFunc
Function Parameters:

value: INPUT("Row", "no row found")


Advanced > Inputs:

Name: Row
Type: Number



Then on the step itself I have:

With these inputs:

Name: Row
Value: =[Row]



I have a "Row" column in my data.
Everything looks like it's set up correctly but every time I create a new item to trigger the automation, it runs and the myFunc function logs "no row found".
The automation runs and calls the function, but it's not passing the [Row] to the function, it just keeps passing "no row found".
So what am I missing? What's the right way to pass information through the inputs of the step to an apps script function?

There is no need to use advanced inputs in this scenario.
To pass the row ID of your new Entry, pass the [Row ID] field (or whatever the key to that entry is) as your function parameter.
Here is a photo for a better understanding of how to set it up in Appsheet Automation (In my entry the key is [TransactionID].

